# search in xml file - batch script

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, scripting, devops

I need your help in batch script (cmd)

I need to write a batch script which take a specific value from xml file and put it into a variable.

So this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
      <artifactId>parent-k</artifactId>
      <groupId>cyt</groupId>
      <version>6.6.3.22-1-DEV-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>ctx.d</groupId>
    <artifactId>view-ct</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ctrer</name>
    <version>6.6.3-21-DEV-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
      <view-core.version>6.6.3.22-1-DEV-SNAPSHOT</view-core.version>
    </properties> 
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
          <configuration>
            <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
            <stopKey>vaadin</stopKey>
            <scanTargets>
              <scanTarget>src/main/webapp</scanTarget>
            </scanTargets>
            <!-- Redeploy every x seconds if changes are detected, 0 for no automatic 
                            redeployment -->
            <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
            <webApp>
              <contextPath>/</contextPath>
              <configurationClasses>
                <configurationClass>org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.MavenWebInfConfiguration</configurationClass>
                <configurationClass>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</configurationClass>
                <!-- <configurationClass>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</configurationClass> 
                                    <configurationClass>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</configurationClass> 
                                    <configurationClass>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</configurationClass> 
                                    <configurationClass>org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.MavenAnnotationConfiguration</configurationClass> 
                                    <configurationClass>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</configurationClass> -->
              </configurationClasses>
            </webApp>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

My question is:
I need to take the value which is located between the < version > tags, I put this line in bold ( ** < version >6.6.3-21-DEV-SNAPSHOT **)
I tried many things but I didn't manage to do it because there are some < version > tags in the xml, and I need only the specific that I mentioned. 
The version that I need isn't the version which is placed under the parent tag, but this is the version which appears after the tag "name". thanks!

so how can I take this value and put it into a variable?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: batch is quite honestly the worst thing to use to read xml files, this is basically brute forcing the file instead of reading it using the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%a in ('type file.xml^|findstr /b "<version>"') do set "version=%%a"
echo %version%
```

Note: this only works, when the file is exactly formatted as your example. Batch isn't good at processing XML.

**EDIT** to reflect newest info from comments (get the second occurence):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set count=0
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('type file.xml^|find /i "<version>"') do call :getit "%%a"
echo %version%
goto :eof

:getit  
echo ---- %1
set /a count+=1
if %count%==2 set "version=%~1"
```

again: batch is no good solution for XML...

Comment: Wow, thanks!! this is the BEST answer my friend,but can you please explain shortly what are doing here: tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in and here: echo ---- %1
set /a count+=1
if %count%==2 set "version=%~1"

Comment: for the `tokens` and `delims` stuff, see [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). The `echo` line is a remainder of troubleshooting (it's safe to remove this line), [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) increments a `count`er, [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) sets the `version` variable, when the counter is `2` (second occurrence).

Answer (score 1):

Processing XML requires XML-aware tools. You can get away with hacks for a while, but at some point these hacks are going to fail, so why not do it properly right from the start.

**Option 1**: You could download [msxsl.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714), and use an XSLT stylesheet that only extracts a single value:

```
<!-- get_project_version.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:maven="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="Windows-1252" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/maven:project/maven:version" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and run it like so in your batch

```
msxsl pom.xml get_project_version.xsl
```

which will instantly outputs `6.6.3-21-DEV-SNAPSHOT`.

Advantage: Will work with your current cmd.exe/batch approach.

Disadvantage: XSLT and XPath have a learning curve.

---

**Option 2**: Use Powershell, it has this capability built-in, with the `Select-Xml` cmdlet.

```
$ns = @{"maven"="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"}
$result = Select-Xml pom.xml -XPath "/maven:project/maven:version" -Namespace $ns
$result.Node."#text"
```

Advantage: Modern shell, no external dependencies.

Disadvantage: Powershell and XPath have a learning curve.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I cannot use powershell in this case, but I liked your idea. Regarding your first solution - I didn't get it, I tried to run: msxsl pom.xml "version", and I didn't get anything :\ btw - I can't edit the xml itself. thanks

Comment: @JohnPj msxml.exe is an external tool, just running the command won't help, you need to download it.

Comment: Does the namespace (`"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"`) match **exactly** with your XML? You literally left out the most important XML line in your question, so I had to made assumptions.

Comment: @Tomalak I downloaded the exe, but I assume my command isn't right? I run:msxsl pom.xml "version"

Comment: and yeah - the namespace ("http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0") match exactly with my XML

Comment: Huh? `msxsl pom.xml "version"` isn't what my answer has as the command.

Comment: your answer is get_project_version.xsl, and in my xml I don't have this string. I don't understand with what I need to replace it. btw - I can't edit the xml. thanks a lot

Comment: `get_project_version.xsl` is the name of the XSL file I am giving in my answer. You must save it as an extra file. You need to read more closely what I wrote.

Comment: Tomalak - look, get_project_version.xsl isn't the name of XSL in my case. I tried to search this string in my xml, and didn't find it, hence - I'm not sure what it is. In the beginning of my xml I see these lines: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

Comment: In addition, I don't understand how to use an XSLT stylesheet in my xml. I can't edit this xml. I hope you got my point now. thanks

Comment: Look. I gave an XSL file in my answer. XSL and XML are not the same thing. You need two files. Your input and the file I gave in my answer. Please, stop trying random stuff and focus. You don't need to edit any XML. I gave you everything you need in my **Option 1** section and it's not even a lot  to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the [**xpath.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) (without need to download external binaries).As your xml is not valid I've added a root element:

```
@echo off

echo ^<root^> >temp.xml
type version.xml >>temp.xml
echo ^</root^> >>temp.xml

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('xpath.bat temp.xml "root/version"') do set "version=%%a"

echo %version%

del /q /f temp.xml
```

With parsing xml file as xml you'll avoid some potential problems as missing new lines and etc.

Comment: The XML is a Maven POM file, so there's a default namespace involved here.

Comment: @Tomalak - then you can change the xpath with a valid one.

Comment: Does xpath.bat support default namespaces?

Comment: @Tomalak - no, it is rather simplified tool (if you wish you can try add such  a functionality - it is mainly jscript code). Though as an xml with namespaces is still valid xml it should be possible to extract the version. Can you paste somewhere (temporary) the whole xml content so I can try to construct a valid xpath query?

Comment: I'm not the OP, so I can't. :) Since JScript will use MSXML internally, adding that would be possible. That's actually not a bad alternative to my `msxsl.exe` approach. But as it is right now, it wouldn't work for the OP's input.

Comment: I am not sure regarding the root element. I need to replace it with what? can you give an example? thanks

Comment: @JohnPj - is the xml you posted the whole file? Because it is not a valid xml. If it is not the whole file you can paste it somewhere so I can check it and create a valid xpath query.

Comment: No solution to the given problem will **not** involve XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Here's Windows Scripting Host file in JavaScript that takes 2 parameters (filename, XPath), and outputs all elements of all nodes that match the XPath provided.

Take the file, name it xmlparse.wsf and run it with cscript.exe as follows.

```
cscript /nologo xmlparse t.xml "/xml/version"
```

You can optionally provide a namespace prefix and namespace URI, for those suffering from namespace overkill.

```
cscript /nologo xmlparse t.xml "/nso:xml/nso:version" "nso" "http://namespacesRoverkill.com"
```

Be sure to set your default script engine to the console (not window) output, as follows

```
cscript /H:CScript
```

The actual script for xmlparse.wsf

```
<package>
<job id="t1">
<script language="JScript">

    var fso = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
    var objArgs = WScript.Arguments;

    var strDOMObject = "MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument";
    var xml = new ActiveXObject( this.strDOMObject );

    if( objArgs.length < 2 ) {
        WScript.Echo( "Usage: file.xml xpath [namespace] [namespaceuri]" );
        WScript.Echo( "Outputs the value(s) of all matching nodes" );
        WScript.Quit( 1 );
    }
    var strFileName = objArgs(0);
    var strXPath = objArgs(1);
    var strNamespacePrefix = null;
    var strNamespaceURI = null;

    if (fso.FileExists(strFileName) == false) {
        WScript.Echo( "Cannot locate " + strFileName );
        WScript.Quit( 1 );
    }

    if( objArgs.length == 3 ) {
        WScript.Echo( "Please include both a namespace and namespaceuri" );
        WScript.Quit( 1 );
    }

    // namespace prefix and URI provided, load 'em up
    if( objArgs.length == 4 ) {
        strNamespacePrefix = objArgs(2);
        strNamespaceURI = objArgs(3);
    }

    try {
        if( !xml.load( strFileName ) ) {
            var strErrMsg = '';
            strErrMsg = xml.parseError.reason;
            if( xml.parseError.srcText != "" )
                strErrMsg += "Source: " + xml.parseError.srcText + "\r\n";
            if( xml.parseError.line != 0 )
                strErrMsg += "Line: " + xml.parseError.line + "\r\n";
            if( xml.parseError.linepos != 0 )
                strErrMsg += "Position: " + xml.parseError.linepos + "\r\n";
            throw new Error( xml.parseError.errorCode, strErrMsg ); 
        }

        if( strNamespacePrefix != null ) {
            xml.setProperty( "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:" + strNamespacePrefix + "='" + strNamespaceURI + "'");
        }

        var nodeList = xml.selectNodes( strXPath );
        if( nodeList != null ) {
            for( var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++ ) {
                WScript.Echo( nodeList[i].text );
            }
        } else {
            WScript.Echo( "No matching nodes found in " + strFileName + " with XPath \"" + strXPath + "\"" );
            WScript.Quit( 1 );
        }

        WScript.Quit( 0 ); // success
    } catch( e) {
        WScript.Echo( e.description );
    }

</script> 
</job>
</package>
```

Comment: The OP's XML file will have a default namespace, a solution therefore needs to support namespaces.

Comment: Beautiful!! thanks!!! but in this case, the only language that I can use is: batch (because I need to refactor a batch script and I can't replace it with another script). thanks

Comment: FWIW, I've edited the post to include a namespace version, for those that "really" need namespaces (yuk).

Answer (score 1):

This Batch file get *the version which appears after the tag "name"*, as you indicated.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "tag="
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=<>" %%a in ('findstr /N "<name> <version>" file.xml') do (
   if "!tag!" equ "name" set "version=%%b"
   set "tag=%%a"
)
echo Version: %version%
```

Comment: I like that `:)`

Comment: Wow, beautiful answer, I missed this answer. Thanks! Can you please explain what did you do here: for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=<>" and here: if "!tag!" equ "name" set "version=%%b"?

Comment: The `for /F` command get the `tokens` numbers `2,3`in the line delimited by `delims=<>`, so `%%a` is the tag and `%%b` is its value. The `if "!tag!" equ "name" set "version=%%b"`command set `version` variable to the version when `tag`variable is `name`.